# Hyperledger Fabric: Where can one find complete description of network-config.yaml?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Where can one find complete description and schema of the [network-config.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/balance-transfer/artifacts/network-config.yaml) file used in Hyperledger Fabric?

Specific Questions:

1. W.r.t.

   orderers:
     orderer.example.com:
       url: grpcs://localhost:7050

   ```
   # these are standard properties defined by the gRPC library
   # they will be passed in as-is to gRPC client constructor
   grpcOptions:
     ssl-target-name-override: orderer.example.com

   tlsCACerts:
     path: artifacts/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt
   ```

Is `tlsCACerts.path` path to the CA that issued the TLS server certificate? If not, then what is it? How to extend this section to cover the case when mutual TLS is enabled?

1. How can one specify the information in https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-mutual-tls.html in network-config.yaml so that one can use [Client.loadFromConfig](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-network-config.html) to do the equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where can one find complete description and schema of the
>   network-config.yaml file used in Hyperledger Fabric?

documentation for v1.4 can be found at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/connectionprofile.html

> Is tlsCACerts.path path to the CA that issued the TLS server certificate?

correct. the client machine will validate the TLS certificate returned by the server against the certificate in `tlsCACerts.path`. To illustrate:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile <tlsCACerts.path> <cert-returned-by-server>
```

> How to extend this section to cover the case when mutual TLS is enabled?

has to be done in javascript code. not supported in yaml or json.

> How can one specify the information in https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-mutual-tls.html in network-config.yaml so that one can use Client.loadFromConfig to do the equivalent?

not possible (supported). has to be done by making call to `setTlsClientCertAndKey` as shown in that link

Answer (score 0):

Where can one find complete description and schema of the network-config.yaml file used in Hyperledger Fabric?

It's being worked on. There is currently a major undertaking to change the way configuration is handled in Fabric. Probably a few months off from completing the work, but the ultimate goal is a well defined configuration, with the ability to generate a template config with descriptions of all options.

Follow the work here:

https://jira.hyperledger.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/FAB-14758